# webpack: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve folder ('src')

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm getting this error message from `webpack-dev-server`:

```
ERROR in multi main
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'D:\projects\living\user-platform\project\src' in 'D:\projects\living\user-platfo
rm\project'
 @ multi main
```

Currently, my webpack config files are:

- [webpack.common.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/134e19006a6f8da06bf4123c35d8a8a7)
- [webpack.dev.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/365e8cc433ef629d6246776dce0e3092)
- [webpack.prod.js](https://gist.github.com/jeusdi/919e6228b753cbe67f72edfd613a8c99)

Current directory structure:

```
├───.vscode
├───config
│   ├───html-elements-plugin
│   └───modules
└───src
    ├───app
    │   ├───another
    │   ├───dashboard
    │   ├───error
    │   ├───layout
    │   │   ├───chat-sidebar
    │   │   │   └───chat-message
    │   │   ├───navbar
    │   │   ├───notifications
    │   │   ├───pipes
    │   │   ├───sidebar
    │   │   └───widget
    │   ├───login
    │   ├───profile
    │   ├───scss
    │   ├───signin
    │   └───validate
    └───assets
        ├───css
        ├───demo
        │   └───notifications
        ├───fonts
        │   ├───font-awesome
        │   ├───glyphicons
        │   └───google
        ├───icon
        ├───img
        │   └───people
        └───mock-data
```